# VB.Net pulling dates from Excel into Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel

I've been having loads of trouble pulling dates from excel and loading them into an array. I have code that should, for all intents and purposes work, but nothing is being loaded into the array. When I do a search in the array for a value, no matter what it is, it says it has been found at Index -1 in the array. Code is as follows.

```
Dim d As String
Dim strDate(0 To 35) As String
Dim dCell As Object
Dim tDate As String = Now.ToShortDateString

    Dim dCount = WFMBook.Range("G2:AO2").Cells.Count
        For y = 1 To dCount Step +1
            For Each dCell In WFMBook.Range("G2:AO2").Cells(y).Value.ToString
                d = WFMBook.Range("G2:AO2").Cells.Value.ToString
            Next
            strDate(y) = d
            TextBox1.Text = strDate(0)
        Next
```

And then after all the data is supposedly loaded into the array (I have the textbox function to check whether things are in the array -- no results are printed into the textbox.) I perform this function:

```
Dim dindex As Integer = Array.FindIndex(strDate, Function(s2) s2 = tDate)
MsgBox("Found Date " & tDate & " at index " & dindex)
```

As I said previously, though, the MsgBox shows that it was found at index -1, and no array results are ever printed to the textbox. I believe it has something to do with Excel Date/Time somehow. How can I get this to properly load the dates into a string format ex "12/3/2015" into an array?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Locals window and set a break point.  Step through the For y loop.  I think your problem is in 'For Each dCell In WFMBook.Range'  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm trying to load each cell in that range into the array. It has worked previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your problem is you are not iterating across your range correctly. You just need to reference the `Cells` property respective to your test range of `WFMBook.Range("G2:AO2")`.

```
Dim checkRange = WFMBook.Range("G2:AO2")
Dim dCount = checkRange.Cells.Count

For y = 1 To dCount
    ' Row postion (1) remains the same, but the column is incremented with y.
    d = checkRange.Cells(1, y).Value.ToString
    strDate(y) = d
    TextBox1.Text = strDate(0)
Next
```